# Generate a dataframe from array containing min max in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a array which specifies min max of variables and looks like:

```
> A

array([[0.2, 0.4],
       [0.4, 0.6],
       [0.4, 0.6],
       [0.20, 1.])
```

I would like to generate a dataframe where each column takes random value between the min and max values specified in the array, assuming a uniform distribution. So I expect something like the following with 100 rows.

```
>df
    A      B     C    D
0  0.22  0.49  0.55  0.92
....
```

I tried

```py
out = pd.DataFrame()
out['var1'] = np.random.randint(A[0][0],A[0][1], size = (100,1))
out['var2'] = np.random.randint(A[1][0],A[1][1], size = (100,1))
```

Which does not work and gives error:

```
> Range cannot be empty (low >= high) unless no samples are taken
```

Comment: `out['var1'] = np.random.uniform(low=a[0][0],high=a[0][1], size = 100)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `itertools.starmap`:

```
from itertools import starmap

df = pd.DataFrame(list(starmap(lambda *x: np.random.uniform(*x, size=100), A))).T
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
          0         1         2         3
0  0.202284  0.576393  0.454379  0.281535
1  0.394127  0.548972  0.457263  0.830006
2  0.217800  0.453033  0.484151  0.815607
3  0.378785  0.501277  0.401935  0.443096
4  0.212777  0.556653  0.436207  0.331099
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0.2, 0.4],[0.4, 0.6],[0.4, 0.6],[0.20, 1.]]))

# b = a.apply(lambda x,: print(x), axis=1)
b = pd.DataFrame(list(a.apply(lambda x: np.random.uniform(low=x[0],high=x[1], size = 100).T, axis=1)))

print(b.T)
```

The output is:

```
           0         1         2         3
0   0.357169  0.442365  0.569691  0.321225
1   0.336422  0.530320  0.505476  0.410900
2   0.391133  0.581999  0.522609  0.694121
3   0.227375  0.521012  0.549536  0.656963
4   0.271649  0.595682  0.430994  0.287333
..       ...       ...       ...       ...
95  0.385812  0.478079  0.599705  0.631283
96  0.214605  0.568494  0.488586  0.696451
97  0.329692  0.401601  0.514235  0.662928
98  0.229644  0.462015  0.543876  0.909954
99  0.373864  0.529524  0.454594  0.713829

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```